# How to Set multiple div to “position: fixed and top:0” at the top of a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

we want to align divs are fixed top in run time dynamically. Now fixed top has been working. But my problem is 2 different divs are coming same position in one by one. so we are not able to see other divs so we want do like this [image: this]  we try some thing in JSFiddle Please check this below code and Please help to solve this problem.

```
var fixmeTop = $('.fixme').offset().top;
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            var currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
            if (currentScroll >= fixmeTop) {
                $('.fixme').css({
                    position: 'fixed',
                    top: '0',
                    left: '0'
                });
            } else {
                $('.fixme').css({
                    position: 'static'
                });
            }
        });
```

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/Boomanikandan/em1uo638/1/#&togetherjs=fjIeodovPF)

Comment: You can just wrap divs in one to set only one div fixed. So in your case you have to append divs that have to be at the top

Comment: yes i have to append divs to be at the top. but that divs are dynamic for example we have 1,2,3,4,5,6 divs. what are the divs they select divs that only append to top like 2,3,6 thats divs only top remain are same position

Comment: No-no, you have to create ONE div with position fixed and top:0. Then dynamic divs has to be appended in those div

Comment: that dynamic divs how i have to appended in those div

Comment: @G Boomanikandan you have to modify code in place that those divs are creating. They must be appended to the div you specify , not at the body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var counter = 0;
var height = 0;

$('.fixme').each(function() {
  if (counter > 0) {
    height = height + $(this).outerHeight();
    $(this).css({
      'top': height + 'px'
    });
  }
  counter++;
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 200vh;
}

.fixme {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #E4E4E4;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="fixme">fixed item 1</div>
<div class="fixme">fixed item 2</div>
<div class="fixme">fixed item 3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can do this way also

```css
        .main {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0px;
        }
        .fcard, .scard {
            border:1px solid #333;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
        }
```

```html
<div class="main">
     <div class="fcard">
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
         tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
         quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
         consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
         cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
         proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
     </div>
     <div class="scard">
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
         tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
         quis nostrud exercitation ullamco .
     </div>
    </div>
```